# How can I unzip a zip file in linux and/or windows without additional libraries?

Tags: node.js

The command should work in linux or windows environements, and not depend on any additional libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully in the Unix/Linux world we can pretty much rely on `unzip` being present. Assuming a "modern" Windows with Powershell v5, there is an equivalent, `Expand-Archive` command.

```
const os = require("os");
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

async function unzip(file, destination) {
    const expandCommand = os.platform() === "win32" ?
        `powershell -command "& {&'Expand-Archive' ${file} -DestinationPath ${destination}}"` :
        `unzip ${file} -d ${destination}`;

    const { stdout, stderr } = await exec(expandCommand);
    return stderr ? Promise.reject(stderr) : stdout;
}
```

Only tricky part is how to invoke powershell via exec.

Comment: This is great! wish this question/answer was better referenced, lost hours trying to do with libs with no success